# Mapbox-gl-js giving `message: Not found` error with status (null) and thus CORS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I've been running into a problem for a few days now that I just simply can't understand. Every time I use Mapbox-gl-js or wrappers like ReactMapGL, I get a CORS error saying `The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://events.mapbox.com/events/v2?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjYW5nZXZhcmUiLCJhIjoiY2w0eTltbzN3MDdsaDNqcG05bmIzdjhoaCJ9.Z8nQ1tZU4hUPf6wmR3rGbw. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).` (I'm going to refresh the API key after this is solved). Going to the link gives the response: `{"message":"Not Found"}`. I know this is not because the API key wrong, because if I add a few characters to the API key to make it wrong, it gives the error that the key is invalid. The access token is just the default public token provided to me by [the dashboard](https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens/).

App.tsx

```
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';

const App = () => {
  const [viewPort, setViewPort] = useState({
    latitude: 45.4211,
    longitude: -75.6903,
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 10
  });

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ReactMapGL {...viewPort} mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}>
        marker
      </ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

.env

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=pk.eyJ1IjoibHVjYW5nZXZhcmUiLCJhIjoiY2w0eTRia2wwMXZoMDNtbWxxN2J3Y2g1bCJ9.swneG9rHPGqunt0HeiXDfw
```

In the dashboard I made 1 new token for this project, it has 0 URLs listed in the Restricted URLs option, and even when following step-by-step [this](https://youtu.be/JJatzkPcmoI?t=257) tutorial, it gives the exact same output. Using both `Mapbox-gl-js` and `react-map-gl` libraries give the same output

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check your settings on mapbox to see if you can enable it to be used on localhost.

Comment: @AnthonyDev220 how would I do that? There's nothing in the account settings and as stated in the post, nothing in the access token settings would point to localhost being blocked, even adding `localhost` to the URLs doesn't change anything, so I really would have no clue as to what setting would be causing this.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's on the Mapbox side if you have no token URL restrictions. Maybe check if your network is blocking the domain and subdomain. This bit of code is required, by the way. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/src/util/mapbox.js#L516

Comment: Well that would make sense, except the link the console returns as having a CORS error does have a response (even just going to the link in the post gives the same response) `{"message":"Not Found"}`. Also, the mapbox watermark is loading, which both would suggest it can't be something in my network, going to other web apps using MapBox with for example Angular does load the map as well, which is even weirder. I'm pretty sure that a framework like `react-map-gl` would have that pre-implemented and tutorials show it working without having that code, so it would be weird if that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your app doesn't allow making requests to another origins. Check the same origin policy full description - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Most likely the issue is with your security configuration. Check if you are using [Helmet](https://helmetjs.github.io/) somewhere in the project (most likely in your express server), and if you do, check the contentSecurityPolicy configuration.

If you enabled same origin policy, that means you have to explicitly specify all domains you want to make requests to that are not the same origin that your site, so the policy is satisfied.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in the post for a few reasons:

1. The CORS error isn't the problem, I know how to solve a CORS error, but the problem is the Mapbox server giving the response as put in the post, as a result giving a CORS error, but the problem of the Mapbox server is still there

2. I'm not using any server of my own, the code posted in app.tsx is basically the extent of the code, see the full code [here](https://github.com/LucAngevare/empire-tracker), meaning frameworks (the flagship framework mapbox-gl-js or react-map-gl) handle the requests.